# Django Rest Framework __new__ missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When programmatically accessing certain data from my Django Rest Framework, I occasionally get an error:

**new**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'argument name'

What's odd is that the error is not predictable, in that I may refresh and everything loads fine. So this leads me to believe it may be some kind of data race type situation, but I'll be honest in saying I don't really know where this **new** constructor is coming from.

Can someone shed some light on how Django Rest Framework might be using the **new** constructor so I might have a better idea on where to track down the bug?

(I assume it's a DRF issue since that's what I'm using to access the data, but if it's not that then I'm really lost)

Comment: Can you post a stack trace? This is a needle in a haystack problem without one.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a local caching issue. It occurred when reloading a page with a GET request to my API and I guess the headers weren't in sync. The error went away when sending the max_age to 0, which is something I needed to do anyway.